# PDO update setting field value to 0?

Tags: php, database, pdo

I tried converting my old php sql script into PDO but it keeps setting the users points to 0 instead of adding +15

Heres the original

```
<?php

session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "dbname"); 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE login_users SET Points=Points+15 WHERE username='$username'");


?>
```

Here is the PDO statement I tried to create.  Is my syntax wrong ?

```
<?php

session_start();
$db = new PDO('mysql:host;dbname=dbname;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$Points = $db->exec("UPDATE login_users SET Points='Points+15' WHERE username='$username'");


?>
```

Comment: Also, use bind variables for dynamic input instead of (unescaped!) string interpolation.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Points+15' is a literal. You need it without the single quotes.

```
UPDATE login_users SET Points=Points+15 WHERE username='$username'
```

Better yet, take advantage of parametrization:

```
$Points = $db->prepare("UPDATE login_users SET Points=Points+15 WHERE username=?");
$Points->execute(array($username))
```

Comment: As a sidenote you could also point out how to do that passing `$username` as parameter so that the query becomes more working. Sessions can become tainted and SQL injection then is possible. Prevent that.

Comment: @Asad Wow! I really learned a lot from this.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @AoiHana no problem. You might want to read up on the PDO docs at php.net, there's some pretty good examples.

Answer (score 2):

get rid of these quotes

```
SET Points='Points+15' WHERE
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution !